# Override error messages in BindingResult

Tags: java, spring-mvc, data-binding, error-handling

I am using Spring MVC 2.5 .

I have fields where numbers should only be the allowed in put. And I get the exact error message on my UI I was looking for . Something like

```
Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.math.BigDecimal] for property executionThresholdAmount; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

I don't want to display that kind of  message to the user. I do use message.properties file to organize texts to be displayed.

The only thing I need is I wanted to overwrite the error message for specific fields. I couldn't do that but here is the trick I was using for

```
if(result.hasFieldErrors()){

            List<FieldError> bindingErrors=( List<FieldError>)result.getFieldErrors();
            BindingResult fieldErrors=new BeanPropertyBindingResult (offerSetting, "offerSetting");
            for(FieldError error :bindingErrors ){
                String field=error.getField();                
                fieldErrors.rejectValue(field, "invalid.amount."+field);


            }


            result=fieldErrors;
            #more code
```

What I am doing is I created BeanPropertyBindingResult which is an implementation of BindingResult and populated the error fields with the message I want and pass the reference to result object so it gets displayed. However, I am now getting both the default messages

```
like

Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.math.BigDecimal] for property executionThresholdAmount; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

and also the message I wanted. Something like

```
"The amount for field price you entered is invalid"
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: never did it before but maybe you can add try catch in your binding class?

Comment: @DanielRobertus look the selected answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding to your messages properties file somethig like this:

`typeMismatch.objectClassName.field=Your custom message`

In your case:

`typeMismatch.offerSetting.amount=The amount for field price you entered is invalid`

Works for me :)

Comment: Sweeeet!!! You make me happy just in the morning. I couldn't imagine how my day is going to turn out. :D

Comment: I think it will be helpful to also include the prop file registration in servlet.xml file.

 <bean id="messageSource" 
 class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basenames" value="folder_name_under_src/prop_file_name" />
 </bean>